# Beamer - create subsubsection page

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I know I'm not supposed to use subsubsections, but I have this hierarchical structure that I need to describe so I have to use them. I want to define a subsubsection page that looks like the picture, basically Section Title/Subsection title - Subsubsection title. I've played with the section title to generate the image. How can I achieve that result?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis} 
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title - Subsubsection title}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\frame{\subsectionpage} %ideally I'd have a \subsubsectionpage command
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis} 

\makeatletter
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]{%
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{22em}
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}
    \insertsectionhead\\[-1ex]
    \usebeamertemplate*{progress bar in section page}
    \par
    \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\else%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection title}%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}%
      \insertsubsectionhead{} -- \insertsubsubsectionhead
    \fi
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\subsubsection{subsubsection title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]