# setting subsubsection title page

Tags: beamer, sectioning

Please would you find what is wrong in the `\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection page}` definition. The subsubsection title page is not displayed. I do not want to use the solution mentioned in answer posted; I want to find what is wrong in my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.2em\rlap{\hskip-2em\textcolor{violet}{\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.}}\textcolor{violet}\inserttocsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
\begingroup
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\thesection-~\insertsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
\begingroup
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\thesection-~\insertsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vspace*{-1.pt}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsection title}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\thesection.\thesubsection.~\insertsubsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection page}
{
\begingroup
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsubsection title}
    \usebeamerfont{subsubsection title}\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection.~\insertsubsubsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\endgroup
}

\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=blue!40}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamercolor{subsubsection title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{ Openings }
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection{ Ruy Lopez Opening }
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\subsubsection{ Ruy Lopez: Giuoco Piano Defense }
\frame{\subsubsectionpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413052/beamer-create-subsubsection-page

Comment: The mentioned solution is too complicated. I just want to modify my code to display subsubsection title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message from your code tells you that `\subsubsectionpage` is not defined, so you need to define it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection page}{%
\begingroup
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsubsection title}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsubsection title}\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection.~\insertsubsubsection\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\endgroup
}

\newcommand{\subsubsectionpage}{\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection page}}
\setbeamercolor{subsubsection title}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Openings}
\subsection{Ruy Lopez Opening}
\subsubsection{Ruy Lopez: Giuoco Piano Defense}

\begin{frame}
    \subsubsectionpage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your code did not show the subsubsection titles in TOC (I added \setcounter{tocdepth}{3})
the subsubsection title is shown in a separate page and the subsubsection title page did not show the title, just the number of the subsubsection

Comment: I included PrtScrn of the 3 pages

Comment: @Hany As you can see from my screenshot the solution works fine for me. Please include a MWE that shows your problems.

Comment: MWE is too long for the comment, I edited my question to insert my code with your modification, including prtscr of the TOC and subsubsection title pages

Comment: @Hany The correct syntax is `\subsubsection{Giuoco Defense}`  and `\clearpage` does not make any sense with beamer.

Comment: Hello samcarter, my mistake, your solution works fine. I edited my question to show the correct syntax.

Comment: @Hany Editing the question to show the answer will not help any future users. I rolled the edit back to the original question.

Comment: Another nice answer by the Beamer Wizard ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much for your kind words!

Comment: Thank you  samcarter. To avoid editing my question; is there a way to insert a screen shot in the comment box?

Comment: @Hany You can start editing your question, include the image there, copy the url of the image and cancel your edit. Then you can paste the url into a comment. The image will not be displayed, but one can click on it to see it.